# what mistake Am I doing?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
sheet1.activate
activesheet.range(cells(2,"Q"),cells(40,"K")).select 'here the error occurs 
selection.copy
```

The above code works for somtimes and for sometimes throws an Error that with object variable not set what does that mean ? why the above code is not working and if i reopen the file it works again and sometimes dont. But i dont know the reason why it happens. Am i making any mistake in the syntax, If so please let me know the right way to do it. And is there any more efficient way to do to select a set of range ? other than the above ? Thank you in advance

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: what are you doing before and after? are your sure sheet1 is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of this error is usually the omission of a `Set` keyword, e.g.

```
Dim w as Worksheet
w = Sheet1 ' throws error 91
' Correct syntax: 
' Set w = Sheet1
```

If you tell us on what line the error occurs, then a more specific answer will be forthcoming. The syntax of your code sample looks fine, but the error may be due to another line in your code, perhaps not shown in your question.

Is there any more "efficient" way to do to select a range? Personally, I don't like the method you show, with strings as the arguments for `Cells`. Strings are messy, and often lead to mistakes and therefore a loss of work efficiency. Why not:

```
Sheet1.Range(Cells(2,18),Cells(40,11)).Select
' or
Sheet1.Cells(2,11).Resize(39,8).Select
' or
Sheet1.Range("K2").Resize(39,8).Select
```

Or, define K2:Q40 as a named range in your sheet, calling it e.g. "myRange", and do this:

```
Sheet1.Range("myRange").Select ' My personal favourite
```

But why are you using `Select`? This is usually not necessary. Just write:

```
Sheet1.Range("myRange").Copy
```

But then I could ask, why are you using `Copy`, which is a messy method in its own right?...

Comment: yep I got it! So for everywork sheet I must use dim w as worksheet THank you

Comment: A rich answer for a poor question. +1 for @Jean-François.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer.  If Set was missing, it would error every time.

Comment: Yeah, but based on the poor quality of the question, I was betting the problem was inaccurately described, so I extrapolated... Looks like I guessed right. Which I am pretty pleased about!

Comment: Well, I can't disagree with that.  I expected that it had something to do with unqualified Cells references, but this code would have to be in a class module for that to be the case.  And like you said, there's just not enough information to know.